# Gradually decreasing the velocity of an object through animation in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I need to create 2 animations,

- one is of an object going from point *A* to point *B* at a **constant velocity**.
- the other is of an object starting from point *A* but with a **gradually decreasing velocity** as it reaches point *B* until it comes to a **stop**.

I tried decreasing the animation speed every second to achieve this result with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using [curves](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html)

Comment: By animation you mean animation or would Coroutines be a solution?

Comment: @derHugo the subject of this class is animators and animations, so I'm guessing that It's supposed to be with animations, but at this point, I'm thinking of using maybe a Coroutines, but I'm not sure on how to do that neither

Comment: @DerekC. I tried to play a little with them, but I didn't get the slowing effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have noticed when you work with animation in Unity there is no such thing as changing the velocity of an object. What you need to do is give your object an **Animator** and create a new **Animation**.

Then on the animation timeline press the red dot (record button) and then place your object on point A.

Next, on the time line you want to select the exact second that you want your object to come to a stop and after that move the object on point B.

Now, the more seconds there are in between the 2 keys, the more time it's going to take for the object to travel.

To make it gradually slower instead of it just travelling slowly:

On the animation panel you will see 2 tabs. Dopesheet and Curves. Hit Curves and play around with them till you have a satisfing result.

[Documentation on using Curves](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationCurves.html)

Comment: I know that if I stretch the keys in the animation it will take longer, but at the end, it will go to the same speed, but I need it to start at some speed, and end in another, let's say (i don't know what units unity use) it starts at 10 km/h and as it approaches the end start decreasing 9,8,7....2,1,0 km/h I don't know if the curves could help me with that